# I imported 3D models that was ripped from game file(model-resource), but it has black things around eyes and mouth

Tags: modeling

why is this happening?
Model file is from [The Model's Resource, Nintendo model archive](https://www.models-resource.com/nintendo_switch/supersmashbrosultimate/model/28660/)
[image: Isabelle]

*Edited after seeing comments(thanks!)
I saw your comment and reply, and watched some videos about bsdf, still I got a problem as you can see my pictures below. I somehow erased the shadows, but the eyes became too tranparent and also are looking weird.

***I only changed the eyes***, not the mouth at all. so the question is on eyes, at this point.

[image: with opaque mode]
with opaque mode

[image: with alpha blend mode]
with alpha blend mode

[image: when bitmap connected to color is muted(opaque)]
when bitmap connected to alpha is muted(opaque)

[image: when bitmap connected to alpha is muted(opaque)]
when bitmap connected to alpha is muted(opaque)

[image: in render mode with opaque mode]
in render mode with opaque mode

**Solved, Thank you so much! :D
[image: Yay!]

Comment: tip: always show nodes (shader-editor) when asking about material problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems to be a case of transparent parts rendered as black (this is not a bug, but a feature in material view)

You are in material-view mode and not render mode. When you go into render-mode it should appear correct (if nodes are setup properly).

2. If nodes are incorrect, It normally is the following:

Its possibly that the alpha output of the image-texture is not connected to the alpha of your principled bsdf.

Edit: As I suspected, the nodes are not properly setup. All you have to do is connect the 'Alpha' output from image texture to 'Alpha' input of Principled BSDF

Note: in the first image below, on the right side, it mistyped "Rendered View". I meant to say 'Material View/Viewport Shading mode'. Its a small mistake, I noticed late.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, first of all, Thanks for your reply! I actually didn't know what a bsdf even means and, what a node named bsdf at the end does. Still, I have problem. Could you take a look and what's going on? I just edited and added some photos that might help(with render img, nodes! yay!) ( thanks for pro tip)

Comment: Yes, the mistake that you made is what I initially guessed. Don't worry, its easy to fix. Editing my answer. Please accept it after your issue is resolved.

Comment: Hey! Your instruction worked! It's working perfectly fine for every facial expressions! I think now I fully understand how this node works(not really, but I think I'm getting now).

Comment: I of course accepted it! you are such a 3d model master. Also, if you mind, may i have a short question? Everytime I get any 3d model files that were ripped out from game resource files, they are most likely messed up like this, and I am curious why it is like this. For example I have to set every body parts-which contains transparent area- to set render mode as "Alpha blend" mode, so that I can see them without disturbance. I wonder how those game modes do not have such black shadows 'In game'.

Comment: Why do I see this black stuff in blender's normal render mode, and why can I not see that in game(as in Super Smash bros. Ultimate)

Comment: Transparent parts are shown as black when transparency is not calculated. This is what happens in Material/Viewport Shading mode, not Render Mode. Render Mode shows it current i.e., invisible. This is for performance optimization.